# Cost of updating entities in datastore (and, possible to append properties)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a two part question.

Let's say I have a entity with a blob property...

```
# create entity

Entity(ndb.Model):
    blob = ndb.BlobProperty(indexed=False)

e = Entity()
e.blob = 'abcd'
e_key = e.put()


# update entity

e = e_key.get()
e.blob += 'efg'
e.put()
```

So questions are:

1. The first time I put() that entity, the cost is 2 Write Ops; how many Ops does it cost to update the entity, as in the above example?
2. When I added 'efg' to the property, the old property had to be read into memory first, does app engine provide a way to append the old value without reading it first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no partial updates.  Every time you overwrite the whole entity.  Numbers of indexes will also have an impact on cost.  You might like to have a look at https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write  for a detailed breakdown of what happens.

Comment: So updating the entity costs exactly the same as creating it?
And even if I only change one property, the other properties are overwriten "by themselves"? That seems inefficient.

Comment: Thats the way it works, we're not in Kansas any more Toto ;-) Though updating will cost more than creating as you have a read followed by write.

Comment: "we're not in Kansas any more Toto" ...was there another comment deleted, who is Toto :P ? Thanks.

Comment: http://philosiblog.com/2012/05/15/toto-i-have-a-feeling-were-not-in-kansas-anymore/

Comment: nice article. well this pretty much answered both my questions. thanks.

Comment: In this particular instance the cost of an update is the same as a cost of a write.  When you have an entity with multiple properties, there is the write cost for writing the entity, and the write cost for updating indexes.  Properties that do not change during the update don't incur the cost for updating indexes, so its possible for updates to be less expensive than the initial write.